# Mythology SE needs more commitments

Tags: discussion

As you probably know, a fair number of people come to History.SE looking for answers regarding mythology only to find out that not only is it off-topic here, but it's not on-topic anywhere on Stack Exchange.

But there is an **[Area51 proposal for a mythology SE site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58307/mythology?referrer=u4bI8H2eeMTa1Ktl-HOLsw2)**, in the "commitment" stage, which means it needs more people to hit commit, to say that they will be active on the site beta.

Anecdotally from my own circle, I feel like there's significant overlap between history buffs and mythology nerds, so I thought people from here might be interested in making the mythology site happen.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​[Mythology.SE](http://mythology.stackexchange.com/) is now public.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

FWIW, the poster asked in chat if it was OK to post this, and I was encouraging.

If nothing else, it will be nice to have something legit to do with the vaguely history-flavored mythology questions we get from time to time, aside from just closing them.

I don't think there's much of any direct overlap, so I don't see this stack actually cannibalizing any good History questions from our own beta stack.

Also on the plus side, I freaking love Mythology. Particularly the non-Greek stuff I don't know as much about. So there's that. :-)

Answer (score 0):

While I would like it, I'm not sure how much traffic such a SE could produce.

Maybe it would have been better to merge that topic into an already active SE…